# How to tranfer large file from server to client using udp

Tags: java, udp, file-transfer

I want to do a project on java. My objective is to transfer large files from server to client using UDP. I found that UDP doesn't support data larger than 84kb ? So how to do this one..? Is there any way ?

Comment: Through Java Object Serialialization

Comment: thanks   Hanzallah Afgan, can you be more specific i'm kinda new to this..

Comment: Yes. I will give you an example.

Comment: UDP does not guarantee packet delivery ... With a file you'll end up with something incomplete.

Comment: thanks scartag  and  Hanzallah Afgan

Comment: *Why* are you wanting to use UDP?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TCP and Object serialization. File is already something seiralized.

Answer (score 4):

If this is for any practical purpose whatsoever, you should use TCP. If it's for learning, however, it will be a very interesting exercise: you will essentially need to reimplement the functionality that TCP provides on top of IP, so I suggest you read up on that first. Here's a summary:

TCP works by breaking down the data into smaller chunks that fit inside individual IP packets. Since the IP packets might be reordered en route and some might not appear at all, each packet has a sequence number that allows the recipient to reassemble them into the right order. The recipient must also *acknowledge* each received packet; if the sender doesn't receive an acknowledgement of packet *x* within a certain amount of time, it will resend packet *x* (and keep doing so at regular intervals until it is acknowledged). This means that the recipient must also be prepared to receive multiple copies of the same packet.

So in your situation, you need to decide upon some format for your UDP datagrams: for example, the first eight bytes might contain a random identifier that the sender chooses for the file (so that different files can be transferred simultaneously without the datagrams getting mixed up), the next four bytes will be the sequence number, and the rest of the packet will be a chunk of the actual file data. Maybe the first packet should contain the filename as well, and the total number of datagrams the file consists of. An acknowledgement datagram need only contain the identifier and the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP Client and Server programs for transferring files. The Server sends the file and the Client receives the file. 
For file transfers you should use the TCP(Transmission Control Protocol) which is connection oriented protocol that ensures the successful delivery of data at the other end while for real time streaming we use UDP(User Datagram Protocol) that is is connectionless protocol where no acknowledgement is made between the two. **You should do this through TCP not UDP.**

In UDP 64 kilobytes is the theoretical maximum size of a complete IP datagram packet.

See [java socket programming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) for better understanding.

**Server**

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Server {

    private ServerSocket sSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private OutputStream os;
    private File file;
    private JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

    public Server() throws IOException {

        sSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("Waiting for incoming connection request...");
        socket = sSocket.accept();
        jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
        int count = 0;
        byte[] b = new byte[1000];
        System.out.println("Uploading File...");
        while ((count = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
           dos.write(b, 0, count);
        }

        fis.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("File Transfer Completed Successfully!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Server();
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Client{

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private InputStream is;
    private File file;
    private JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();

    public Client() throws Exception {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        System.out.println("Waiting for File");
        jfc.setSelectedFile(new File(dis.readUTF()));
        jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
        file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int count = 0;
        byte[] b = new byte[1000];
        System.out.println("Incoming File");
        while((count = dis.read(b)) != -1){
            fos.write(b, 0, count);
        }

        fos.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("File Transfer Completed Successfully!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new Client();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hum... Socket and ServerSocket are TCP APIs. For transmitting though UPD protocol, you must use DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket instead.

Comment: Yes I know that quite well. I have mentioned that.

Comment: @LittleSanti See at the very first line of the answer.

Comment: This is wrong answer. You do not even possess the basic logic. You should understand who defines the specification (if UDP is not suitable, it does not mean that TCP must be used). You should not provide TCP solution unless somebody is ready to accept it. Secondly, the fact that Ethernet does not support 100k packet, does not mean that we should use alternative medium to transfer longer files. UDP should be able to fulfill the specification.

Comment: He wants to send files. For that you should use TCP. Otherwise through UDP you will get files corrupted. UDP doesn't guarantee the successful delivery of files at the other end.

Comment: [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html)UDP (User Datagram Protocol) is a protocol that sends independent packets of data, called datagrams, from one computer to another with no guarantees about arrival. UDP is not connection-based like TCP.

Comment: Again, you demonstrate that you do not possess the little logic. Another flaw is that you say that UDP cannot be used even for sending short messages (because their delivery is not guaraneteed!). You say that UDP should not be used for anything. This is how argument works.

Comment: I would like you to lambast the TFTP service: `TFTP is a simple protocol for transferring files, implemented on top of the UDP/IP protocols using well-known port number 69.` You see -- you need UDP to transfer the files.

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste I don't know what you are? I let you to give him the answer not to me. You don't understand what I have written in the description of the answer. No more comments Please. Help him.

Comment: i want to use udp because to do broadcasting...(many to one and one to many communication and TCP does'nt support this ...what should i do please somebody help...

Comment: @NakulNarayanan Who is saying that you cannot broadcast with TCP?You have to select all the clients from the list and then send the data to each. You have to make your own strategy for that. Broadcasting has not concern with UDP or TCP in your case.

Comment: @HanzallahAfgan What I am? Certainly not a human. Only unhuman can reject the shit you have written. You have written that TFTP (file transfer over UDP) is impossible. The fact that you do not try to match this fact with your statement is additional confirmation that you do not possess elementary logic to tie facts together. It is very expected that you will use this your power to dictate me what I must not understand. It is also absurd to ask to help "him" when you muddle the waters.

Comment: thanks to all your replies.... but no one suggested  me to how to do it.... so i guess thats it..i'm on my own on this one...